# Visual Studio 2013 debugging buttons grayed out

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

When I am debugging in Visual Studio 2013 at times the debugging buttons are grayed out when the code has hit a break point. The only way to continue is to use the hot keys. Does anyone know why this is? You can see what I am talking about highlighted in red in the image below.

Thank you in advance.

[image: Debug Not Working]

Comment: I have seen other issues with debugger in VS2013 that were resolved by a 'repair'. For Any weird VS behaviour I always recommend: Disable all add-ins/extension. (Start in safe mode) and try a repair.  May not fix your issue but fixes and identifies a lot of issues.

Comment: Can you also verify if the items in the Debug menu are greyed out?

Comment: @HeXanon, within the actual debug menu the items are NOT grayed out.

Comment: Other than maybe deleting the items from the toolbar and re-adding them I have no answer.  I think you are looking at needing a repair or worse.

Comment: The thing is that I had this same problem with the same exceptions when I was using VS2010. The exceptions that appear like this are only before the winform displays, after the app displays visually the buttons work exactly as they should.